# How can I replace addObserver with publisher in receiving notifications from NotificationCenter

Tags: swift, swiftui

Currently I am using `addObserver` method to receive my wished notification in my ObservableObject, from the other hand we can use `publisher` method to receive wished notification in a View, I like to use `publisher` method inside my ObservableObject instead of `addObserver` method, how could I do that? How can I receive/notified the published value from publisher in my class?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model: Model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .onReceive(orientationDidChangedPublisher) { _ in
                print("orientationDidChanged! from View")
            }
        
    }
}
```

---

```
var orientationDidChangedPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
```

---

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    init() { orientationDidChangeNotification() }

    private func orientationDidChangeNotification() { NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(readScreenInfo), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil) }
    @objc func readScreenInfo() { print("orientationDidChanged! from ObservableObject") }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways. First using the Combine framework (don't forget to import Combine), and the other using the usual way.

```
// Without Combine:
class MyClass1 {
    let notification =  NotificationCenter.default
        .addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
                     object: nil, queue: .main) { notification in
            // Do what you want
            let orientationName = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ? "Portrait" : "Landscape"
            print("DID change rotation to " + orientationName)
        }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(notification)
    }
}

// Using Combine
class MyClass2 {
    let notification = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
        .sink { notification in
            // Do What you want
            let orientationName = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ? "Portrait" : "Landscape"
            print("DID change rotation to " + orientationName)
        }
    
    deinit {
        notification.cancel()
    }
}
```

In `deinit` you should remove all the observers, like i've shown above.

EDIT:

#### more about `deinit`:

`deinit` is the opposite side of `init`. It is called whenever your instance of the class is about to be removed from the memory.
If you are using the `Combine` way, it is fine to don't use deinit because as soon as the instance of the class is removed form the memory, the `notification` which is of type `AnyCancelleable` is removed from the memory as well, and that results in the notification being cancelled automatically.
But that automatic cancellation doesnt happen when you are using the normal way, and if you dont remove the observer you added, you'll have multiple observers listening to the notification. For example if you delete the `deinit` in the `MyClass1`, you'll see that the `"DID change rotation to "` is typed more than once (3 times for me) when you are using the class in a SwiftUI view, because the class was initialized more thatn once before the SwiftUI view is stable.

Comment: ok, I tried and i removed `deinit`, everything was normal as before I am using the normal way not Combine, I did not receive multi notification,

Comment: You did not, but i did! Better be safe than sorry. Removing the observer is also advised by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver . Also as a note, `Publisher`s are part of the combine framework, so you can't avoid them if you want to use the `NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for:)`

Comment: there is no doubt that you are right, I just report what I observed! So let me ask my question in this form, should I run a code or condition to activated `deinit`? or we just put it there and define it and iOS would automatically use it, this is my question, who is going run `deinit` part?

Comment: Yes, thats not our task to use deinit, Swift automatically does that before remving the instance from memory. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same `publisher(for:)` inside your class:

```
import Combine

class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
            .sink(receiveValue: { (notification) in
                //do something with that notification
                print("orientationDidChanged! from ObservableObject")
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, you used combine, is it the only way of doing this?

Comment: If you look at the NotificationCenter documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) the options are observers, or publishers. Publishers are part of Combine.

Comment: in my question I did not import Combine and also working

Comment: I needed `Combine` because in order to access the `AnyCancellable` type. If you're just using the publisher (which is still part of Combine) and you don't need the type, you don't need it. Is there a reason you want to avoid Combine?